Angular 17: localStorage is not defined Error After Saving Changes and Browser Stuck in Reloading State
When i run project in angular 17 it runs successfully. However when i made some changes in code and save changes then:
The browser page stucks in a reloading state
Also this error shown up:
Error during ngOnInit: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
Here is my ngOnInit code block:
async ngOnInit() {
    try {
      await this.fetchUsers();
  
      this.chatService.fetchMessages();
      this.chatService.messages.subscribe((messages) => {
        this.messages = messages;
      });
  
      const users = this.authService.getUsers();
      const { username, id } = this.authService.getUserNameFromToken() || {};
      this.name = username ?? '';
      console.log("Display token name:", this.name);
      let token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
      console.log("Token: ",token);
      this.id = id ?? '';
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during ngOnInit:", error);
    }

  }



If I remove the localStorage code, the reloading issue still persists

please share the code of your guard and auth service

@UsamaIkram for starters comment out all the code in ngOnInit except localStorage (do something simple e.g. localStorage.clear()). This will help you in determining if the root cause is in calling your services or not.

@BennyHalperin, I removed all the code from ngOnInit, but the same issue occurred: the browser page gets stuck in a reload loop

@UsamaIkram can you please share your routes?

@AshishMishra
`import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { ChatComponent } from './chat/chat.component';
export const routes: Routes = [
{path:'',component:SignupComponent},
{path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
{path:'dashboard',component:ChatComponent}
];
`

@UsamaIkram is there any method you have called directly from the HTML? and also can you create a one more component with new route to check if same issue is there with new component also

I'd start with making ngOnInit non-async. It's not supposed to be async; instead, it should work with observables instead of promises.

I feel it's a problem with SSR and localStorage, see e.g. this SO related

It maybe a Browser Cache Issues
Sometimes, the browser cache or cookies can cause infinite reloads
or you can check for the infinite loops and debug the logs
async ngOnInit() {
  try {
    console.log("Starting ngOnInit");

    await this.fetchUsers();
    console.log("Fetched users");

    this.chatService.fetchMessages();
    console.log("Fetched messages");

    this.chatService.messages.subscribe((messages) => {
      this.messages = messages;
      console.log("Received messages:", messages);
    });

    const users = this.authService.getUsers();
    const { username, id } = this.authService.getUserNameFromToken() || {};
    this.name = username ?? '';
    console.log("Display token name:", this.name);
    
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.localStorage) {
      let token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
      console.log("Token: ", token);
    } else {
      console.log("localStorage is not available.");
    }

    this.id = id ?? '';
    console.log("ID:", this.id);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during ngOnInit:", error);
  }
}

